# Oracle: SQL select date with timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
SQL> select * from booking_session;

BK_ID|BK_DATE
-----|-------------------------
    1|18-MAR-12 10.00.00.000000
    2|18-MAR-12 10.25.00.000000
    3|18-MAR-12 10.30.00.000000
    4|18-MAR-12 10.35.00.000000
    5|18-MAR-12 10.40.00.000000
```

I am trying to write a `sql` query that selects all records that matches a certain date, however I am using timestamp for the `BK_DATE` field and no matter what I try it my query yields no results.

**SQL**: I have tried the following queries but they yield no results

1.

```
select * 
from booking_session
where bk_date = to_date('18-03-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

2.

```
select * 
from booking_session
where bk_date = to_timestamp('18-03-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

3.

```
select * 
from booking_session
where bk_date = to_date('18-MAR-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

It only works when I set the whole date value like;

```
select * 
from booking_session
WHERE bk_date = '18-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000';


CREATE TABLE BOOKING_SESSION(
  BK_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  BK_DATE TIMESTAMP,
  BK_BOOKER NUMBER,
  BK_CUSTOMER NUMBER,
  BK_TREATMENT NUMBER,
  T_SESSION_DATETIME TIMESTAMP,
  STAFFAPPOINTED NUMBER,
  BK_ROOM NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO BOOKING_SESSION VALUES (
  1,
  TO_TIMESTAMP('18/03/2012 10:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),
  1,
  1,
  1,
  TO_TIMESTAMP('20/03/2012 11:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),2,1
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer provided by  Nicholas Krasnov

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOKING_SESSION
WHERE TO_CHAR(T_SESSION_DATETIME, 'DD-MM-YYYY') ='20-03-2012';
```

Answer (score 20):

You can specify the whole day by doing a range, like so:

```
WHERE bk_date >= TO_DATE('2012-03-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND bk_date <  TO_DATE('2012-03-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

More simply you can use TRUNC:

```
WHERE TRUNC(bk_date) = TO_DATE('2012-03-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

TRUNC without parameter removes hours, minutes and seconds from a DATE.

Comment: +1 but I'd use TO_TIMESTAMP because that's the datatype of `bk_date`.

Comment: None of the above yielded anything, only when i give it the whole (18-MAR-12 10.40.00.000000) only it works

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos Did you change the date to the one you are looking for ('2012-03-18')?

Comment: What is the datatype of the bk_date column? Its sounding like its a string, in which case you need to convert it to a date before you can compare it against a date.

Comment: timestamp is the data type of bk_date, here is the insert statement: INSERT INTO BOOKING_SESSION VALUES (1,TO_TIMESTAMP('18/03/2012 10:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')

Comment: can you paste the output of a sql*plus select then? as Droid's answer is correct. note that if you use TRUNC or TO_CHAR as this and another answer has shown, you'd want a function based index on that coloumn if you wanted not to full table scan on it. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c166/2

Comment: David for your other oracle question, why did you delete the question after getting the answer from the community?