# Sql Query using 'Like' is giving results but using '=' does not returns any result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

The Query using LIKE :(This query when fired gives the desired result)

`select * from catissue_audit_event where event_timestamp like '16-DEC-14'`

But when using query with '=' results in an empty resultset

`select * from catissue_audit_event where event_timestamp='16-DEC-14'`

Here event_timestamp is of type Date

Strange thing is that the query runs for other dates such as:

`select * from catissue_audit_event where event_timestamp='15-DEC-14'`

What can be the issue? I already checked for leading and trailing spaces in the data

Output after running the first query:

[image: Output after running the first query:]

Comment: could you share the sample output which you got from first query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337635/oracle-sql-select-date-with-timestamp

Comment: Have you tried to use TO_DATE to convert timestamp to date?

Comment: i am getting the data for '15-DEC-14' using the same query but getting trouble while retrieving results for '16-DEC-14'

Comment: @Panter please look at the edit

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` on `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` columns. Your query is subject to implicit data type conversion and does not do what you think it's doing. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes i want to use '=' only but it's not giving me results, so tried using 'LIKE' and it is producing the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle a `DATE` (and of course a `TIMESTAMP`) column contains a time part as well.

Just because your SQL client is hiding the time, doesn't mean it isn't there.

If you want all rows from a specific day (ignoring the time) you need to use `trunc()`

```
select * 
from catissue_audit_event 
where trunc(event_timestamp) = DATE '2014-12-16';
```

Be aware that this query will not use an index on the `event_timestamp` column.

You should also not rely on implicit data type conversion as you do with the expression `event_timestamp = '16-DEC-14`. That statement is going to fail if I run it from my computer because of different NLS settings. Always use a proper DATE literal (as I have done in my statement). If you don't like the unambiguous ISO date, then use `to_date()`:

```
where trunc(event_timestamp) = to_date('16-12-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

You should avoid using month names unless you know that all environments (which includes computers **and** SQL clients) where your SQL statement is executed are using the same NLS settings. If you are sure, you *can* use e.g. `to_date('16-DEC-14', 'dd-mon-yy')`

Comment: but why am i getting results when i pass some other date like '15-DEC-14' in query using '='

Comment: @Abhishek: maybe you do have some `date` values that have the time `00:00:00` on that day. You need to change the *dispaly* format of dates (and timestamps) in your SQL client in order to see that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is different is different to the solution to your issue.

The solution to your issue is to stop performing date comparisons by implicit conversion to a string. [Convert your string to a date to perform a date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql/10178346#10178346):

```
select * from catissue_audit_event where event_timestamp = date '2014-12-16'
```

I cannot stress this enough; **when performing a date comparison *only* compare dates.**

Your column EVENT_TIMESTAMP is being implicitly (this is bad) converted to a date in accordance with your [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817), which you can find as follows:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters
```

This governs how [date-data is displayed and implicitly converted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970516/458741). The reason why `LIKE` works and and `=` doesn't is because your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is masking additional data. In other words, your date has a time component.

If you run the following and then re-select the data from your table you'll see the additional time component

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
```

Thus, if you want all the data for a specific date without constraint on time you'll need to remove the time component:

```
select * from catissue_audit_event where trunc(event_timestamp) = date '2014-12-16'
```

Comment: got your point , but why am i getting results when i pass some other date like '15-DEC-14' in query using '='

Answer (score 0):

have you tried matching the event_timestamp format example: DD-MMM-YY with the date that you are passing?

Comment: not facing any issues while retrieving other entries

Comment: There is no such thing as a date "format" (and would be `DD-MON-YY` if there was one)

Comment: @Ben here is how you format your SQL query, u can start with 
Select * from tablename where FORMAT(event_timestamp,'DD-MMM-YY') = '15-DEC-14' and he says SQL Query not Oracle, and if its oracle you can use the to_char method like this: TO_CHAR(vent_timestamp, 'DD-MMM-YY')
but Abhishek I don't know why it is not working for you.